# How to detect which React component triggers onKeyUp event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say we have a single `onKeyUp` handler:

```
handleKeyUp: function(e) {
  /* handle stuff */
},
```

And we have a couple of input components, both of which could trigger the handler:

```
<input type="text" ref="login" onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp} />
...
<input type="text" ref="pwd" onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp} />
```

How do I make it so the handler can detect if the `onKeyUp` was triggered from `login` or `pwd`?

A scenario is where I detect a tab press on `pwd` and then I proceed to try to save the text fields (but not where I tab off from `login`).

I've tried looking into detail of `e.target` but couldn't figure out how to reference the originating component.

**Update**

Sorry, must not be thinking clearly. Yes, `e.target` is a reference to the originating component. I was looking to get a handle on `ref` to get the value. But I don't need the ref, I can just get the value from `e.target.value`.

Comment: Have you tried `e.target`?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I did. I updated my post to clarify this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As stated in [React's `Event System` documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) :

> Your event handlers will be passed instances of SyntheticEvent, a cross-browser wrapper around the browser's native event. It has the same interface as the browser's native event, including stopPropagation() and preventDefault(), except the events work identically across all browsers.

Thus, an instance of a `SyntheticEvent` is passed to your callback

```
handleKeyUp: function(event) {
    /* event is an instance of SyntheticEvent 
       from wich you can extract the currentTarget 
    */
},
```

**Edit** : In case you really want to access component's `ref` name before doing anything, here is how you could do it in ES6 :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.handleLoginKeyUp = this.keyUpHandler.bind(this, 'LoginInput');
        this.handlePwdKeyUp = this.keyUpHandler.bind(this, 'PwdInput');
    }

    keyUpHandler(refName, e) {
        console.log(refName);
        // prints either LoginInput or PwdInput
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" onKeyUp={this.handleLoginKeyUp} ref="LoginInput" />
                <input type="text" onKeyUp={this.handlePwdKeyUp} ref="PwdInput" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You're right. As per updated question, I was actually looking to get a handle of ``ref`` to get the value, but I can just do ``e.target.value``.

Comment: how does that work with the bind a function to an element reference? I mean is the ref just the same as the native element so I can use "This"?